# I want to export read data to csv or feather etc

Tags: python, pandas

for file_name in list_of_files:

```
if '.int' in file_name:

 print(file_name)
 rd.read_int(file_name,sensor)
 temp_df=rd.df.to_csv('test5.csv')
```

I have almost 2000 file which i am reading using loop. As you can see this work but over write "test5.csv"

I want to create different csv to different file

Comment: Is `.int` the extension of your input files?

Comment: yes it is binary data, i read it with read_int fucntion, it is working but now i want to export this data to csv or any other format.

Comment: the read all 2000 file so i want as it reading and export it

Answer (score 0):

As `.int` is the extension of your input files, you could just keep the name without extension and use `.csv` as the extension:

```
for file_name in list_of_files:
    if file_name[-4:] == '.int':            # process .int files
        print(file_name)
        rd.read_int(file_name,sensor)       # read the file
        new_name = file_name[:-4] + '.csv'  # csv file name with same "prefix"
        rd.df.to_csv(new_name)
```

Comment: but you can not read that file with pd.read_feather